# C++ pointer variable of class

Tags: c++, variables, pointers, private

Here's an example to explain my question:

```
//myfile.h
class thing
{
public:
    void doSomething();
private:
    Book *text;
};
```

Now, inside the doSomething method, how do I call the Book object's method read()? Read() is nonstatic. For this example lets say I made a thing object called obj, which called doSomething().

Would the proper call be:
    obj->read(),
    or this.obj->read()

Comment: The answer is completely unrelated to pointers. It’s the same behaviour for *all* members. Furthermore, evaluate whether a pointer is really what you want. In most situations, pointers have no place in modern C++.

Comment: why not just test? text->read()

Comment: @RiaD The testing approach fails miserably with C++ due to the pervasive existence of undefined behaviour.

Comment: Not to add to the confusion, but you could use the dereference operator `*` and do something like this `(*obj).read()` but the dereference arrow does that for you. In general, make sure to check your pointer `!= NULL`

Comment: You **really** need to start reading a [C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 4):

The proper call would be `text->read()`. You can also use`this->text->read()`.

In your example, there is no need to use `this`. Also note that `this` is a pointer, so `this.next->read()` would not even compile.

**Edit** if you "made a thing object called obj, which called doSomething()" then there does not even have to be a `this`, depending on *where* you instantiate the `thing`. If the `thing` is not a data member of another object, then you simple need:

```
thing obj;
....
obj.doSomething();
```

In any case, you cannot call `obj.read()` since `thing` has no `read()` method.

Answer (score 1):

It would just be:

```
text->read()
```